# Conditional formatting over multiple sheets

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I am a bit of an MS Excel amateur, but I'm pretty sure that Excel can handle something like this. I have a spreadsheet where the first sheet is a master sheet presenting the codes and description of some tasks, followed by some (multiple) workrole sheets, each having a small subset of those codes that conform to that workrole.

```
Master Sheet
Code      |  Description   |  Module 1  |  Module 2  |  Module 3 | ...
 4             XYZ                Yes          No           No
 6             ABC                No           Yes          Yes

Workrole Sheet
Code      |  Module 1      |   Module 2 |  Module 3  | ...
 4
 7
```

I want that if someone types in `Yes` in `Module 2` corresponding to the Code `6` in the Master sheet, `Yes` appears in `Module 2` of all the workrole sheets that have that particular code `6` in them. Plus, that particular row gets coloured green (but not so important). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve involves two different actions (just give the most basic way below):
1) To copy the "Yes" to each Workrole sheet:

- Assume you don't have a very large number of worksheets and codes (otherwise it would be slow)
- Assume Code is unique.
- Method: search the same "Code" from Master sheet and copy the corresponding "Module 2" value
- In each of your Workrole sheet, use `=index('Master sheet'![column of
  Module 2 in master], match([cell contains the Code of your entry],
  'Master sheet'![column of Code in master],0))`

2) To highlight the row:

- Select all data row in Workrole sheet, add new conditional formatting
  rule using formula
- enter `=($[column of Module 2][first data row]="Yes")`  <-- note the "$"
- Select the format you want to highlight the rows

Comment: so, the formaula for (1) should be something like - ``` =INDEX('Master'!E, MATCH(A5, 'Master'!A, 0)) ``` ?

Comment: what does "cell contains the code of your entry" mean here?

Comment: "cell contains the code of your entry" refers to column 1 of each row.

Comment: Thanks! This works!! :) For cells that have no value in Master sheet, I get "0" in the corresponding Workrole cells. Is there a way to change that to " " ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378567/index-match-returns-0-for-blank-cell-want-it-to-be) should serve the purpose. (suffix the `index()` function with ` & ""` )