# Excel formula to fill a column based on value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

How can I make a formula such that when update a value in `Completed` for a particular value of `ID`, it automatically gets filled in all cells of `Completed` for that particular `ID`?  And, when I remove the value from one cell in `Completed`, it automatically gets removed from all cells in `Completed` that correspond to that value in `ID`.

For eg. in the data below, I'd like the three blank cells automatically filled with `4`, `6` and `5` respectively.

```
Role      ID      Completed
 A         1          3
 A         2          4
 A         5          3
 A         8          6
 B         2          
 B         8
 B        10          5
 C        10           
 C        15          2
```

Comment: In this case, you will need a VBA based `Worksheet_Change` event code. Formula solution will not be possible unless you have the complete column as formula column and completed is a LOOKUP based column.

Comment: Happy to do it anyway possible. But, since I'm an Excel amateur, can you guide me on how to do that? :)

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij btw I tried something like this earlier using a formula - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397515/conditional-formatting-over-multiple-sheets/ , but the requirements have slightly changed since then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A Worksheet Change Solution

**What does it do?**

- When a value in `Target Column` is changed to a **new value**, the value in
  the same row of `Source Column` is being looked up in the same `Source Column`.
  With each found value, the value in this (found) row in
  `Target Column` is changed to the mentioned **new value**.

**Usage**

- To run the following successfully, both codes have to be copied
  to one workbook appropriately: the first to a **sheet** module and the second to a **standard** module.
- There is nothing to run here, everything runs **automatically**.
- The only thing that could be changed are the **last three values** in the short code.

### The Two Codes

**1. Sheet Module**

The following code is to be copied into a **sheet** module e.g. `Sheet1`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    updateColumn Me, Target, "B", "C", 2
End Sub
```

- Instead of `"B"` and `"C"` you can use the numbers `2` and `3`.
- You can change the values as you see fit.
- You can copy it into multiple sheet modules and change the parameters
  for `SourceColumn`, `TargetColumn` and `FirstRow`.
- `Me` and `Target` stay the same.

**2. Standard Module**

The following code is to be copied into a **standard** module e.g. `Module1`

```
Option Explicit

Sub updateColumn(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                 TargetCell As Range, _
                 ByVal SourceColumn As Variant, _
                 ByVal TargetColumn As Variant, _
                 Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 4)
    
    If TargetCell.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then GoTo MoreThanOneCell
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet.Columns(TargetColumn)
    If Intersect(TargetCell, rng) Is Nothing Then GoTo NotInTargetColumn
    
    Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo EmptyTargetColumn
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then GoTo FirstRowBelowLastRow
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = rng.Row
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(SourceColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Row > LastRow Then LastRow = rng.Row
    Else ' Empty Source Column. Don't care.
    End If
    If FirstRow = LastRow Then GoTo OnlyOneCell
    
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, TargetColumn), _
                          Sheet.Cells(LastRow, TargetColumn))
    If Intersect(TargetCell, rng) Is Nothing Then GoTo NotInTargetRange
    
    Dim ColOff As Long: ColOff = Sheet.Columns(SourceColumn).Column - rng.Column
    Dim Target As Variant: Target = rng.Value
    Dim Source As Variant: Source = rng.Offset(, ColOff).Value
        
    Dim i As Long, tVal As Variant, sVal As Variant
    tVal = TargetCell.Value
    sVal = TargetCell.Offset(, ColOff).Value
    Debug.Print TargetCell.Address, tVal, _
                TargetCell.Offset(, ColOff).Address, sVal
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        If Source(i, 1) = sVal Then
            Target(i, 1) = tVal
        End If
    Next i
    'Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng.Value = Target
    
CleanExit:
   ' Application.EnableEvents = True
LastExit:
    Exit Sub

MoreThanOneCell:
    'Debug.Print "More than one cell."
    GoTo LastExit
NotInTargetColumn:
    'Debug.Print "Not in Target Column."
    GoTo LastExit
EmptyTargetColumn:
    'Debug.Print "Empty Target Column."
    GoTo LastExit
FirstRowBelowLastRow:
    'Debug.Print "First row below last row."
    GoTo LastExit
OnlyOneCell:
    'Debug.Print "Only one cell."
    GoTo LastExit
NotInTargetRange:
    'Debug.Print "Not in Target Range."
    GoTo LastExit
    
End Sub
```

You can uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines to monitor the behavior of the `Change event` in the `Immediate window` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) in `VBE` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've encountered a bug with this approach. When I use a filter on the 'Role' to select a subset of the roles, the procedure fails to update the values. Would you have any idea why that's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.

- Your setup is in column A, B & C
- Prepare a LOOKUP table in column E & F as shown below.

  ```
    ID    Completed
    1     3
    2     4
    5     3
    8     6
    10    5
    15    2
  ```

Then in column C (cell C2), you can use a simple formula like below and copy down as much needed.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$E:$F,2,0),"")`

So, as soon as you update status in column E & F, it will get updated in the formula column.

Comment: this approach wouldn't work for me sorry! I don't know the values for 'Completed' here. I just want to automate this worksheet, so that when someone else types in these values, their work is reduced.

Comment: @harry04 please see reply from VBasic. Suggest if that works for you. If it doesn't then I will look into VBA based option.