# Auto-fill column value based on other column fails when a filter is added

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have made a macro-enabled worksheet where when I fill in a cell in column `C1`, `C2`, `C3` etc. corresponding to a column value in `ID`, all the cells corresponding to that particular `ID` are filled with the same value in `C1`, `C2` etc. And, when I remove the value from one cell in `Cx`, it automatically gets removed from all cells in Completed that correspond to that value in `ID`.

For eg. in the data below, I'd like the blank cells (`__`) automatically filled with `Y`s in the columns `C1`, `C2` and `C3` when I type in the `Y`s in the other cells.

```
Role      ID         C1     C2    C3         ....
 A         1                 Y    
 A         2          Y            Y
 A         5          Y      Y
 A         8          Y
 B         2          __           __ 
 B         8          __
 B        10                       Y
 C        1                  __
 C        10                       __
```

For this I used the answer posted by @VBasic2008 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62560087/2552610). Thanks @VBasic2008! :)

This method works fine for me. **However, when I add a filter to the `Role` column to filter for only rows with Role `A` and `B`, I encounter a bug and the method doesn't work as expected.** Can anyone tell me why that is, and how to resolve that?

**EDIT:** Changed the mock data and explanation a bit to better portray my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply iterating over each ID cell until empty cell in that row is found.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim ID As Long, completed As Variant, r As Long
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Sheet1.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "Completed" Then
    ID = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
    completed = Target.Value
    r = 2
    Do Until Sheet1.Range("B" & r).Value = ""
      If Sheet1.Range("B" & r).Value = ID Then
        Sheet1.Range("C" & r).Value = completed
      End If
      r = r + 1
    Loop
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a much shorter solution. Would it scale well if I have ~4500 rows in the worksheet?

Comment: You can set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` at the beginning of the code and set it back to `True` at the end. This should speed the code up as no much time will be spent on redrawing the window.

Comment: The code will stop once the first empty cell in column B (ID) is found.

Comment: But, I'd like to update for all possible non-empty cells. For example, if there are 5 empty cells with `ID` = 10, I'd like to update all 5 cells.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, the code stops at first empty ID column cell. ID = 5 is not that cell. Have you tried running the code?

Comment: Sorry! I misread it as `first empty cell in C (Completed)`. The code doesn't work for me on a replica of the above mock data. Can you help please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219111/discussion-between-harry04-and-eniac).